# SRS: Can these to be included?

Tags: architecture, documentation, requirements, srs

Think we are creating the "Glossary" of an SRS in tabular format. It has "Terms" and "Definition" as columns.

I know the glossary of SRS includes "Terms" such as QA, HTML, KPI etc, and their meaning under "Definition" column. It seems like it is a place where we describe "Initials". However, can I add the following under the "Terms" and describe them? (This is a SRS used for a Fire and Security alarming system, one of our final year projects)

```
zones
central manned control area
sprinkler
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the glossary in your software requirement specification (SRS) is there to help people know what you mean by the terms you use. There is nothing special about initialisms; include all technical terms.

Comment: You're welcome. For what it's worth, I'm not sure how widely understood the term *SRS* is; I'd usually refer to it as a *requirement spec*.